# Formatting XSLT to an A4 page size to print via a browser

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to do something possibly really simple, but I just dont understand this as to why its not working from what I have read up on.

Example XML:

```
<example>
    <item>
        <name>something1</name>
        <qty>1</qty>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>something2</name>
        <qty>1</qty>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>something3</name>
        <qty>2</qty>
    </item>
</report>
```

Sample XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4" page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm">
        <fo:region-body margin-top="20mm" margin-bottom="20mm"/>
        <fo:region-before extent="10mm"/>
        <fo:region-after extent="10mm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>

<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4" >
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="report/item"/>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>

<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4" >
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-before">
        Some head content.
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>

<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4" >
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-after">
        Some foot content.
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>

</fo:root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="qty" />, <xsl:value-of select="name" /></fo:block>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired Result:
  I want to be able to do a transformation that appears in a browser, but creates a page with common Header and Footer that always occurs, and the  information that fills up the page until it runs out of room, then starts another with the same Head and Foot information. 
  ie - if there was LOTS of Items, and I got the  and  of each one on a line until it ran out of A4 space, then continued on another A4 page.
  It is not important to have to see the page layout in the browser, but do need to see it layout that way in the Printing.
Have I missed something here? or am I on the right track?

also suggestions of good sources on learning XSL-FO would be appreciated, as most I have seen are hard to follow with this idea, w3schools does a tutorial, but it describes it as stand alone, without need for and XSLT.

Added (9th Apr 2014)
Sample Raw XSL instead of XSL-FO

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<h3>Some Form</h3>

<table>
<tr>
<th>SomeName</th>
<th>Qty</th>
</tr>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Report/Item"/>
</table>

<h4>Some footer</h4>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="qty"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't know of any browser that understands XSL-FO natively. Are you just sending the XSL-FO directly to the browser, or are you converting it somehow to HTML that the browser understands?

Comment: Originally I had done a transformation using XSLT to view a page layout on the browser, but looking ahead when I do a larger report I will need the ability to control the layout and force it to conform to an A4 format and choose where the data breaks. So it doesn't even have to be XSL-FO if there is another way. I am aware <div> with css can do some methods of text wrapping and truncating but I don't think it would handle with the transformation filing it with a constantly varying length of content

Comment: Are there any other suggestions out there that can use HTML to control the XLST output to an A4 page size in the browser? I have included a raw XSL file to use as an example above.

Comment: I believe you need to add some CSS styling to your HTML to tell it how to print. This has nothing to do with XSLT, at least not yet. It can become an XSLT question once you have figured out what the result of the transformation needs to look like (should it include a link to an external CSS stylesheet or should it generate the required CSS code in the resulting document itself).

Comment: Yeah for the moment I have used CSS to control the size of some <div> areas to partition the XSLT into them, so some appears in the head area, and some appears in the foot area, yet the surrounding <div> sets the page size to A4 dimensions. My current thought is when I run a larger report and get more lines in the XSLT table, I will overflow the content <div> and how do I get it to start a new page layout??

Comment: I think you are going down the wrong road. If you want paginated output, generate PDF, not HTML.

Comment: I am afraid you are missing my point. Do a Google search for "css print page size".

Comment: I Like Michael Kay's idea, and understand what Michael.Hor is saying, but the trouble I am stuck with is the tools that are provided to me locks me into the browser from the program (which generates my XML data source). It looks like i need some way to come out of the browser to then use XSL-FO or generate a PDF instead. are there some easy ideas how to then alter to get to these results VIA the browser? (security issues are a major hurdle with getting the browser to launch another program or task)

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. You cannot attach a CSS stylesheet? Your XSLT can point to it (i.e. tell your HTML to look at it). And even if you cannot do that, you can include the CSS code right in your HTML - again, produced by your XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes, I do point my XSLT at the CSS and it does style area's and yes I have looked into that "@media print" actually very useful in other areas for me. but I am not able to see how I can get the CSS to flow to a new area when the XSLT fills one area. for example, if I the CSS/HTML gave me a <div height="20px"></div> and the XSLT was able to fill a target <div> with enought content to fill 'height="80"' then what do you need to do in the CSS/HTML to allow it to fill 20px, then create another <div height="20px"></div> and so on until all the content is processed out.